# SPARQL Update operations

Tags: sparql

According to SPARQL Update 1.1 there is a GraphStore where all the operations take place. I would like to ask if we can create more than one unnamed RDF graphs(except the default) in the GraphStore through the various operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot, per the [Section 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#graphStore) of the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/) there is only ever one unnamed graph:

> A Graph Store is a mutable container of RDF graphs managed by a single
>   service. Similar to an RDF Dataset operated on by the SPARQL 1.1 Query
>   Language, **a Graph Store contains one (unnamed) slot holding a default
>   graph** and zero or more named slots holding named graphs. Operations
>   MAY specify graphs to be modified, or they MAY rely on a default graph
>   for that operation.

I added the emphasis to the above quote from the specification, essentially there is only ever one unnamed graph.

Technically speaking you cannot even `DROP` this graph since it must always exist (even if empty)

Comment: It of course makes sense if you think about it: graphs are distinguished by name, so if you had two unnamed graphs in a store, how would you distinguish between them?